# getSelectionEnd() getSelectionStart() of Android EditText does not return correct values

Tags: android, android-edittext, selection

```
tt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ni);
button= (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
tt.setText("This is a try");
```

and then

```
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int iStart = tt.getSelectionStart();
            int iEnd = tt.getSelectionEnd());
            Log.v(TAG,"iStart " +  iStart + ", iEnd " + iEnd);

            }

    });
```

Above code results same value of  iStart and iEnd. This happens because when button is clicked, it looses its selection. My question is how to get selection range on click of button or Menu

Answer (score 0):

When the text selection is changed, you can store the start and end position. When button is clicked, you can use the same positions

```
            int iStart;
            int iEnd;
            final EditText yourEditText;
            yourEditText.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                if (MotionEvent.ACTION_UP == event.getAction()) {

                    if (yourEditText.hasSelection()) {
                        // if true, the text in the EditText is selected
                        iStart = yourEditText.getSelectionStart();
                        iEnd = yourEditText.getSelectionEnd();
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            });

        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.v(TAG,"iStart " +  iStart + ", iEnd " + iEnd);

                }

        });
```